# Atalho de navegação entre chaves

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Conforme aumenta a complexidade do código, pode começar a aparecer diversas chaves abrindo e fechando blocos de códigos, porem por diversas vezes la no final do código fica uma serie de chaves assim:

```
     } 
    }
   } 
  }
 }
}
```

Existe alguma forma alguma tecla de atalho, para pular dessa chave de fechamento para a chave que abre o código? eu costumo colocar um comentário na frente informando de onde esta chave pertence

`} // fechamento do if(exemplo)`

porem passa bastante códigos de outros programadores que não tem nenhum tipo de sinalização.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para alternar entre elas, bastar estar com o cursor em uma delas e acionar o comando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

*nota que pode haver alteração no atalho dependendo do teclado, mas isso pode ser facilmente configurado em: *Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard*[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do Mathias já responde sua pergunta.

> basta estar com o cursor na chave de fechamento e acionar o comando
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

Apenas para complementar, segue algumas dicas:

Se você quiser [consultar outros atalhos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/da5kh0wa.aspx) pode ir na opção **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse atalho tem o nome de `Edit.GotoBrace`, nessa opção, conforme mostra a imagem.

**Nota:** isso é importante pois para outros teclados (que não sejam pt_BR), o [atalho poderá ser diferente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501921/go-to-matching-brace-in-visual-studio/2577568#2577568).

Comment: Eu estava complementando a resposta com isso, boa observação!!

Comment: @Mathias, poucos segundos depois de eu postar veio seu complemento kkk.